In the Amazon Fire TV sample app, I'm trying to change the app's background to an image. I Can't figure it out
I've recently started developing a Amazon Fire Tv App, and I've gone spent a ton of time searching for this answer.
Here's part of the tutorial I'm going through: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-app-builder/customize-look-and-feel.html
I'm obviously new to Android Development... but not java development. Any help will be appreciated.
I've googled how to change the background app through the activity_main.xml, but my project does not have one. I've been shown how to do it by adding it to a RelativeLayout... but my project doesn't seem to have one. I even tried change #000000 to @drawable/image_name in teh custom.xml file... to no avail.

I figured it out. Basically I was correct by adding the following in the themes.xml file:
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/image_name</item>

In this case, it was the <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback"> theme.
Turns out that in the BackgroundImageUtils, that background image was being overwritten by a call to :
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawColor(color);

